# How can i assign the ROLE permission with symfony ACL

Tags: php, symfony, acl

I am following this tutorial

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html#creating-an-acl-and-adding-an-ace

`$acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);`

This makes the currently looged in user with `OWNER` permission and he can edit , delete evrything.

Now along with that i want to add `EDIT` permission for `ROLE_EDIT` users
and `MASTER` permission for `ROLE_ADMIN` users

can i assign roles in there

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as following:

```
    $aclProvider = $this->getContainer()->get('security.acl.provider');

    // Use class for object identity as below
    $oid = new ObjectIdentity('acme_post', 'Your\\AcmeBundle\\Entity\\Post');

    $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($oid);

    $securityIdentity = new RoleSecurityIdentity("ROLE_ADMIN");
    // grant owner access to users with above role
    $acl->insertClassAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
```

The magic here is that instead of initiating `ObjectIdentity` with Entity **object** then using `insertObjectAce` , you need to you initiate `ObjectIdentity` with Entity **class** then using `insertClassAce` for the *role-based* `$securityIdentity`.